# Types not found while using Vector in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, vector

I'm trying to use Vector. in a Flash Professional Project, Person being a custom class. Eclipse keep saying it cannot find the type in brackets, even if I try with basic types like int or String:

```
public interface IRenderer
{
    function init(persons : Vector.<int>) : void;
    function render() : void;
}
```

> Type 1046: Type was not found or was
>   not a compile-time constant: int.

I'm working with:

- Flex 4.1 SDK
- Flash Builder 4.0.1 (I've just downloaded it today from adobe.com...)
- Flash Player version = 10.0.45

I've tried to add the Flex SDK in the Build Path but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the playerglobal.swc included in the ActionScript Build Path / Library Path is the Flash 10.X.X version. Sometimes the wrong framework SWCs are loaded

Comment: That was the case, thanks for the tip! By the way, it also didn't compile because the flash player version was set to 9 in Flash CS5, even if the version was 10.0.45 in ActionScript Compiler, inside Flash Builder.

Answer (score 2):

Early releases of FlashBuilder compile for Flash Player 9.x.  Flash Player 9 doesn't support Vector and when a project is configured to target Flash Player 9.x FlashBuilder will show that error if you try to use vector.  Take a look at Project > Properties and select the Flex Compiler in the side-bar.  If Adobe Flash Player options shows 9.x.x, change it to 10.0.0.